# Modify time vector

Tags: matlab, datetime, interpolation

I have a vector of time (format h,min,sec,msec).

```
TIME_=
[120844.950000000
120853.870000000
120854.120000000
120854.370000000
120854.620000000
120854.860000000
120855.100000000
120859.980000000
120900.220000000
120900.490000000

.
.
.
121024.420000000
];
```

Now I wanted to make it uniform with

```
TIME_NEW=[STARTTIME: INCREMENT:ENDTIME ]; % INCREMENT=0.2sec;
```

I see there is function available in matlab `setuniformtime`.

I wish to have like

```
TIME_NEW= setuniformtime(TIME_(:,1),'StartTime',TIME_(1,1),'EndTime',TIME_(end,1),'Interval',0.2);
```

But I don't have this matlab version. Any help?

I have problem in time format

```
ith element
```

TIME_NEW= [ 120859.980000000  , 120859.98000000+0.2 , 120860.18 ]

NOW IT should be `120860.18-->120900.18.`

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying that you want to add 0.2 seconds to each time value?

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth plz see edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the root of your problem is that for time values, you're using numerical values that don't obey normal base-10 (or base-anything) rules.  If you want to continue using this format, what you should do is
1) convert to time in seconds (or some other unit only, in a regular numbering system)
2) create a uniform vector in seconds (or other units)
3) convert back to your other format.

To convert from your format into seconds, you can do the following:

```
#% format = hhmmss.msec
TIME_     = 120859.98 #% and others if you want
HOURS = floor(TIME_/10000);
MINS  = floor(mod(TIME_,10000) / 100 );
SECS  = mod(TIME_,100); #% keep the milliseconds part too
TIME_IN_S = HOURS*3600 + MINS*60 + SECS #% convert hours/mins/secs to seconds
```

You already know how to do the spacing.  All that is left is to convert back to your original format.

```
HOURS_PLACE = floor(TIME_IN_S/3600) * 10000;
MINS_PLACE  = floor(mod(TIME_IN_S,3600),60) * 100;
SECS_PLACE  = mod(TIME_IN_S,60);
UNIFORM_TIME = HOURS_PLACE + MINS_PLACE + SECS_PLACE;
```

This should eliminate the "problem" of the seconds place growing larger than 60, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You've already written the answer, more or less:

```
time_new = [time(1):0.2:time(end)];
```

Of course, it's quite likely that the value of `time(end)` will not be present in the output vector.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth   ith element

TIME_NEW= [ 120859.980000000 , 120859.98000000+0.2 , 120860.18 ]

NOW IT should be 120860.18-->120900.18.